# Try clean reboot and timeout if stuck using python

Tags: python

I want to reboot remote linux(Redhat) machine using python, but sometime remote pc get stuck during reboot. Is there anyway I can timeout if reboot is taking too long? i.e reboot should be aborted if it's taking more than 100s?

```
import os 
restart = raw_input("Do you wish to restart your computer ? (yes / no): ") 
if restart == 'no': 
    exit() 
else: 
    os.system("reboot", timeout(100))...something
```

Comment: [Here's](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/linux-system-restart#2-Constructing-the-required-command) a script that may work for you. Others are simply using `os.system("shutdown -r -t 1")` where the `1` means one second.

Comment: I can't tell from what you wrote as to whether or not you're having privilege problems. I just now tried `os.system('sudo reboot')`. It works. The user is prompted for his password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `os.system`, use `subprocess.run()` instead:

```
try:
    proc = subprocess.run(["reboot"], timeout=10)
except TimeoutExpired:
    ...
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7 not sure subprocess.run() in Python 3.5+. `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'`. Any substitute you see for this in 2.7? subpocess.call ??

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen()` and `Popen.poll()` in a loop. Or I'd highly suggest upgrading to Python 3 instead, Python 2 is already out of support.